# Can someone point out why this nginx location directive is not restricting a url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have the following nginx configuration for my web app:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.stage.app.net;
  root /var/local/app/current/public;


  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|ttf|woff|svg)$
  {
    #oboe_tracing_mode never;
    expires 1y;
  }

  location ~* /trackback/ {
    deny all;
  }

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_friendly_error_pages on;

  rails_env staging;

  include /var/local/app/current/config/nginx/block_malicious.inc;
  include /var/local/app/current/config/nginx/rewrite_projects.inc;
}
```

I am trying to block a `POST` request to the following url `http://app.lan/p/tableau-wordpress-plugin/commits/trackback`

From my nginx readings this should properly block sending anything to this url. However when I make a `Post` request with Postman, the error is reported to errbit. Is this not the right configuration?

I've tried

```
location ~* trackback {}
location /trackback/ {}
location /trackback {}
```

and none of these configurations seem to work. Could someone help assist me with this problem?

Comment: What about `location ~* /trackback {`? You have a trailing slash in your location block but not one on the request

Comment: You were correct about this. Simple typo mistake. Thank you.